# Audio output devices not listed

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

It seems as though Ubuntu simply does not recognise any audio output ports on my PC. I have the usual in-built back panel (coloured) and front panel (mic and headphone) jacks, as well as the audio output through the HDMI port in my NVIDIA video card. Here is the output to some commands I've found on other related threads which I've used to try and debug my issue:

```
~$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 11
    Memory at ef620000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ef600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

--
06:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at ef080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
~$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 11
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

[Here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=a9b19e9ab241ade5ce5c3ce7f3ed585cd0f2a825) is the output of the `alsa-info.sh` script provided by alsa-project.

From the Sound section of the settings menu, no audio devices show except for "Dummy Output", which I'm guessing is to do with the pulseaudio daemon.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling `alsa-base`, `pulseaudio` and `indicator-sound`, removing `~/.config/pulse`, removing `alsa-base.conf` before re-installing, and nothing seems to be helping.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: This appears to be a driver issue.  The hardware is detected (`lspci -v`) No play devices are listed (`aplay -l`) and some input devices are detected (`arecord -l`).

Comment: @stumblebee You're probably right, but I was under the impression that alsa included generic drivers which would work for on-board audio. I've also gone through the steps [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) to try and upgrade the drivers.